# get like count of urls shared on facebook wall (NOT link_stat)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I've Facebook like button correctly in my site.
My meta look like these:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="image url"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="page title"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="page url" />
<meta property="og:description" content="page description" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my_user_id"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_app_id"/>
```

Meta are properly inserted & verified (with Facebook linter)

I'm able to get like count value throught fql query

```
SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="mysiteurl"
```

It's all ok but these values don't include likes made from users on Facebook wall.

For example if I share a link  (www.example.com/myurl) on my wall and my friends or someone else likes the url from their own wall, the like count on www.example.com/myurl doesn't reflect these new likes. It's not a cache delay issue.

It seems to me that, url shared on Facebook lives on its own.

I'd want to get the like count mentioned above.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Liking a stream item (aka post/wall/feed/link) which happens to contain your link is not the same as liking a url.

Comment: Darn... “Fastest Gun in the West” ;)

Comment: It's not going to be easy at all, and might become impossible unless every user who shares your link also is an app user too.  Scan everyone's stream for your link (store the stream id for future reference) keep checking all stored items for a change in count, repeat.

Comment: My domain is connected to a facebook application (I've specified fb:app_id ). Can it be someway useful? I can't scan everyone's stream...( I would add permission to my app) I don't need to know who shared/liked a link, but only how many users..

Comment: You can see if the fql insights would be of any assistance since you don't care to see "who" liked/shared it, but just need the raw stats.

Comment: @DMCS I'll not mark this answer as accepted because you don't provide a solution. Problem is not solved yet. Cheers

Comment: That is the solution. You **must** perform the like action on the actual URL not on a post/wall/feed/link to that URL.